# regular expression for a stream with no order

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to use regular expression(pcre regex), for matching a particular stream.

The stream i want to match is 3e followed by 20s or 09s or 0as, ending with 3c, then replace by just '3e3c'.

3e2020203c to be replaced by 3e3c

3e0920200a3c to be replaced by  3e3c

the thing is, the stream of 20, 09 and 0a(which comes between 3e and 3c - always starts with 3e and ens with 3c however) can come in any numbers and there is no order.

Comment: Have you got anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for PHP.

```
$string = preg_replace('!3e(20|09|0a)+3c!','3e3c',$string);
```

In Perl

```
s/3e(20|09|0a)+3c/3e3c/g
```